# How to get httpd to forward to multiple tomcats for different urls, including /?

Tags: tomcat, apache, mod-jk

Ok

So I've got multiple tomcat instances setup on several AJP ports, I also have Apache httpd listening on port 8090 (cos I've got another app already using 8080 at the moment).

I've successfully mapped urls such as mydomain.com:8090/demo and mydomain.com:8090/preprod to their respective tomcat instances using Jk Mount and the following vhosts config;

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    JkMount /preprod* preprod
    JkMount /demo* demo
</VirtualHost>
```

But I also want the "root" address to map to another tomcat instance, what will become live/production, ie I want mydomain.com:8090/ to map a 3rd tomcat instance.

At the moment nothing happens or changes if I just add to the above config a line;

```
JkMount /* rootwar
```

if I browse to mydomain.com:8090 I just get the same boring apache httpd landing page letting me know its running (ie index.html in httpd/htdocs)

Is it possible to use JkMount to redirect the "root" address stuff to a tomcat instance?

I can see that a rule like /* will also match URLs like mydomain.com/preprod but I was hoping the rules are applied in order so if /* appears at the end it effectively would be a "if its not one of the other environments, then direct to root/production"

Just to be clear I'm trying to setup the following;

```
mydomain.com:8090/preprod --> myApp running in tomcat1
mydomain.com:8090/demo    --> myApp running in tomcat2
mydomain.com:8090         --> myApp running in tomcat3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so turns out I was right about the fall through behaviour of the JkMount stuff, thus a config like;

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    JkMount /preprod* preprod
    JkMount /demo* demo
    JKMount /* root
</VirtualHost>
```

works great, urls with /preprod in them got to tomcat1, /demo goes to tomcat2 and anything else goes to tomcat3 for root. So the JkMount /* root line is obviously the last rule tried and only "catches all" (cos its /*) if none of the other rules have matched the url.

Great.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the jk stuff for while but as far as I remember this isn't possible. We usually worked around this by adding a small html page which redirect to the /root jk mount. Maybe using a mod_rewrite rule might also work.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /root/$1
```

It's also possible to hide the redirect with a bit more complex rewrite rules, an example can be found here:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4277304.htm

Comment: Actually, seems it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

OK - not a direct answer to your question, but...an alternative would be to run each of demo/preprod and prop  in separate instances, each on different ports.

This would have the advantage of simplifying your configuration but more importantly you can make changes to each instance (e.g. bouncing the server) without worrying about affecting the production instance and brining it offline.

Jetty is also very good for situations like this, especially for running quick and dirty dev and demo instances....you can write a very simple script that basically just points at a deployment and starts a jetty instance on it on some port:

```
public static void run(int port, String resourceBase, String descriptor) {
    Server server = new Server(port);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setResourceBase(resourceBase);
    context.setDescriptor(descriptor);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where

- *resourceBase* is /path/to/webapp
- *descriptor* is usually resourceBase+"/WEB-INF/web.xml"

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing, many Tomcats running on many different AJP ports and HTTPD forwarding to whichever port depending on url context. I think you were referring to different external connector ports for direct http access, but as most of these tomcat instances are for external client testing its easier to keep port numbers our of the url :)